# Ingest Mainframe IMS data into Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mainframe, data-ingestion

I am trying to ingest IMS mainframe data into Hadoop. Would like to know if there is a possibility through any of below
 a)Apache Spark or MapReduce jobs.
 b)Any other tools/technologies.

Primary goal is we would like to ingest IMS-mainframe data on a daily/weekly basis that would be run as per schedule

Answer (score 1):

As the IMS mainframe have a **JDBC connector** availaible https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPH2_13.1.0/com.ibm.ims13.doc.apg/ims_odbjdbcintro.htm using Sqoop will be a good starting point. (definitly not an IMS pro just reading the docs )

From **sqoop** you will write data on **hadoop hdfs** and then be able to work with it on Spark Datasets. Sqoop allow you to do full imports or delta one. I will in my point of view recommend recommand using sqoop 1 instead of version 2. With a Cron job to schedule you run you will be schedule as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your preferred choice (a), Apache Spark, is available for z/OS. In fully commercially supported form it's called IBM Open Data Analytics for z/OS, sometimes abbreviated IzODA. IzODA definitely supports direct access to IMS data but with much better performance than remote IMS access. IzODA's IBM Program Number is 5655-OD1, and IBM offers a cloud-based trial so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a JDBC connector for DB2 and high performance unloads for DL/I databases.

There exists products for continues data capture - Attunity and Optim is two of them.

You could make the IMS system deliver MQ or Kafka messages containing the interesting stuff if you don't want it all.

Answer (score 0):

The DB2 interface for mainframe files is not a best option. We had a similar case in my job and JDBC driver didn't offer full set metadata needed for our ingest framework and HIVE table creation.

You could use the simplest flow:

1. Export files to FTP/SAMBA
2. Pull files into HDFS
3. Parse files with Spark or JVM App